# Infinite Loop Crashing, but not in Update Function

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, time, while-loop, timer

These scripts cause Unity to hang. What am I missing here?

I know this is probably the dumbest question ever, considering how Unity handles loops. But I swear I've authored this before and had it work... What am I doing wrong? I get the loop is infinite but it has to continually iterate.

Timer.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Timer{
    float tickTime;
    float lastTicktime;
    bool timerRunning = false;

    public Timer (float tickTime) {
        this.tickTime = tickTime;
    }

    public void StartTimer() {
        timerRunning = true;
        lastTicktime = Time.time;
        GenerateTicks ();

    }

    public void StopTimer () {
        timerRunning = false;
    }

    void GenerateTicks () {
        while (timerRunning) {
            if ((Time.time - lastTicktime) > tickTime) {
                Debug.Log ("Tick");
                lastTicktime = Time.time;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
Timer timer;
    void Start () {
        timer = new Timer (triggerTime);
        timer.StartTimer ();
}
```

Comment: not entirely sure what youre asking -but doesn't look like you ever call `StopTimer()` to set timerRunning to false so it is stuck in the `while` loop

Comment: Your `timerRunning` is always `true`

Comment: Does it specifically need to be a loop?  Why can't you just do a single-run in an `Update()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code can never exit the `while(timerRunning)` loop, since you never execute `timerRunning = false` inside said loop.

Moreover, even if you add `timerRunning = false` inside your `if ((Time.time - lastTicktime) > tickTime) { }` section, you're hanging the execution of the Unity main thread until that condition is `true` (basically, Unity is stopped until at least `tickTime` seconds have passed).

If you need to use a timer AND let Unity execute, then use Coroutines.

Edit: to answer your comment, modify your code like this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Timer {

    float tickTime;
    float lastTicktime;
    bool timerRunning = false;

    public Timer(float tickTime) {
        this.tickTime = tickTime;
    }

    public IEnumerator StartTimer() {
        timerRunning = true;
        lastTicktime = Time.time;
        while (timerRunning) {
            if ((Time.time - lastTicktime) > tickTime) {
                Debug.Log("Tick");
                lastTicktime = Time.time;
                timerRunning = false;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```cs
private Timer timer;
private IEnumerator timerCoroutine;

private void Start() {      
    timer = new Timer(triggerTime);
    timerCoroutine = timer.StartTimer();
    StartCoroutine(timerCoroutine);
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks, but how do I start a coroutine if the timer class doesn't extend from monobehaviour? I can create ienumerators but StartCoroutine is nowhere to be found. Can I call it from the implementation class? I've tried that with little success.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/running-startcoroutine-from-a-non-monobehaviour.233817/ this was helprul

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to use a Coroutine from another non-Monobehaviour class. Basically, to launch a method as a coroutine, you just need it to return a `IEnumerator`, and you're good to go.